# sed/awk to merge multiple line in single line

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have file which contain following

```
ltm pool /Common/foo_mim_pool {
    members {
        /Common/mim-foo-010101-1:5222 {
            address 10.22.1.161
        }
    }
}
ltm pool /Common/foo_ts_pool {
    members {
        /Common/ts-vx-010101-1:6698 {
            address 10.20.1.68
        }
        /Common/ts-vx-010101-1:6699 {
            address 10.20.1.68
        }
        /Common/ts-vx-010101-2:6698 {
            address 10.21.1.199
        }
        /Common/ts-vx-010101-2:6699 {
            address 10.21.1.199
        }
    }
    monitor /Common/ts_monitor
}
```

I want to merge them in single line like following example but look like something i missing to understand

```
ltm pool /Common/foo_mim_pool { members { /Common/mim-foo-010101-1:5222 { address 10.22.1.161 } } monitor /Common/tcp}

ltm pool /Common/foo_ts_pool { members { /Common/ts-vx-010101-1:6698 { address 10.20.1.68 } /Common/ts-vx-010101-1:6699 { address 10.20.1.68 } /Common/ts-vx-010101-2:6698 { address 10.21.1.199 } /Common/ts-vx-010101-2:6699 { address 10.21.1.199 } } monitor /Common/ts_monitor }
```

My first attempt to use following command but its not producing what I want

`paste -d " " - - - - - - - - < file.txt`

`awk 'NR%2{printf "%s ",$0;next;}1' file.txt`

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Just added my experiment command

Comment: plase confirm (in the expected result) you want to add a blank line between each line that starts with `ltm`

Comment: the 1st line of expected output ends with the string `monitor /Common/tcp}`, but this string is not in the sample input; please update the question with either *a)* details on how/when we're supposed to create this missing string or *b)* update the sample input and expected output to insure they match

Comment: please also confirm that we're supposed to convert `members` to `members add`; if that's a typo then please update the question to insure the input and expected output match

Comment: @markp-fuso good catch `add` was typo. I have fixed it.

Comment: Ummmm ... I don't think Cyrus meant for you to pick random snippets of code from an arbitrary tool as a "solution attempt". Unless you explain why you would have thought those work, and how they should have achieved what you're after.

Comment: what about ` monitor /Common/tcp` at the end of the 1st line of expected output? this string does not exist in the input; please update the question to insure input and output match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you're trying to do, using any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk '{ORS=(/^}$/ ? RS : OFS); sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"")} 1' file
ltm pool /Common/foo_mim_pool { members { /Common/mim-foo-010101-1:5222 { address 10.22.1.161 } } }
ltm pool /Common/foo_ts_pool { members { /Common/ts-vx-010101-1:6698 { address 10.20.1.68 } /Common/ts-vx-010101-1:6699 { address 10.20.1.68 } /Common/ts-vx-010101-2:6698 { address 10.21.1.199 } /Common/ts-vx-010101-2:6699 { address 10.21.1.199 } } monitor /Common/ts_monitor }
```

Comment: This is epic, it works!!! I have to google it to understand what magic you did and what are those options in awk.

Comment: Feel free to ask a new question if it's still not clear after reading the awk man page.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of other techniques:

1. print each line without a newline, counting braces.

   ```bash
   awk '
       {sub(/^\s+/, " "); printf "%s", $0} # trims leading whitespace
       $NF == "{" {level++} 
       $1 == "}" {level--} 
       level == 0 && NR > 1 {printf "\n"}
   '
   ```

   ```
   ltm pool /Common/foo_mim_pool { members { /Common/mim-foo-010101-1:5222 { address 10.22.1.161 } }}
   ltm pool /Common/foo_ts_pool { members { /Common/ts-vx-010101-1:6698 { address 10.20.1.68 } /Common/ts-vx-010101-1:6699 { address 10.20.1.68 } /Common/ts-vx-010101-2:6698 { address 10.21.1.199 } /Common/ts-vx-010101-2:6699 { address 10.21.1.199 } } monitor /Common/ts_monitor}
   ```
2. Slurp the whole file as a single string, normalize all whitespace (including newlines) to a single space, and add newlines where needed. This requires the word `ltm` to be constant for every record and only at the start of the record.

   ```bash
   awk -v RS="" '{gsub(/\s+/, " "); gsub(/\} ltm /, "}\nltm "); print}'
   ```

Comment: You should mention those need GNU awk for `\s` (or use `[[:space:]]`).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^ltm/{:a;N;/\n}$/!ba;y/\n/ /;s/\s\+/ /g}' file
```

Focus on lines beginning `ltm` and then gather up all subsequent lines until one starting and containing `}` only.

Then replace all newlines by a space and all multiple white space by a single space.